# How to get nginx to do a redirect to url-encoded query parameter

Tags: nginx

I have a requirement to do a proxy call to url delivered via a query parameter as per example:
My nginx proxy is deployed at: `https://myproxy.net`

if the redirect parameter is not url encoded I can do the call with this block:

```
  location /basepath {
        if ( $arg_redirect = '') { 
          return 400 "Missing redirect directive in request"; 
        }
        proxy_pass $arg_redirect;
        proxy_intercept_errors on;
        error_page 301 302 307 = @handle_redirects;
    }
```

the error intercepts and @handle_redirects then take care of othe 30X codes that might pop up at new destination.
This works for a request:
`GET`: `https://myproxy.net/basepath?redirect=https://destination.com/somepath/uuid`

What do I need to do to make it work for:
`GET`: `https://myproxy.net/basepath?redirect=https%3A%2F%2Fdestination.com%2Fsomepath%2Fuuid`

Additionally as part of spec it has to be pure nginx, not additional modules, lua etc.
Thanks!

Comment: This should work for your use case as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37584656

Comment: @hargut close, but that was actually in reverse of what I need.
I got an answer on StackOverflow, or at least what it seems as close as possible to one without adding lua in.

Comment: For reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65837046/how-to-get-nginx-to-do-a-redirect-to-url-encoded-query-parameter